# ngx-bootstrap's datePicker (onShown) event is triggered before calendar is really shown

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm working with [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap)'s [rangeDatePicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#bs-daterangepicker), and I'm trying to go to the previous month as soon as the `rangeDatePicker` is shown, using it inside my handler function, which is called with the `onShown` event.

Code is the following:
in the HTML

```
 <input id="input-range-dates" type="text" class="form-control" bsDaterangepicker #drp="bsDaterangepicker" [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
                 [(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue" (ngModelChange)="onChanges($event, drp)" [maxDate]="maxDate" placement="bottom"
                     (onShown)="handler('onShown')" (onHidden)="handler('onHidden')" readonly/>
```

As you can see, there are lots of properties, but the only one regarding this question is the

```
(onShown)="handler('onShown')"
```

in the JS

```
handler(value: string): void {
if ('onShown' === value) {
      [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('previous')).filter(element =>
        element.innerText === '‹')[0].click(); // previous Month
  }
}
```

However if I debug it on chrome, I can see that the calendar with the button has not appeared yet, and the click action does not change the month.

Somebody can help with this? I'm stuck..

Comment: Did you find solution to trigger a method after calendar is shown?

Comment: No, I finally ended up using 2 datepickers, to select a range between them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the same handler method for the `onShow` and `onHidden` events:

```
(onShown)="handler('onShown')" (onHidden)="handler('onHidden')"
```

.

```
handler(value: string): void {
if ('onShown' === value) {
      //...
  }
}
```

I suggest to create two separate methods and pass the real `$event` inside:

```
(onShown)="onShow($event)" (onHidden)="onHidden($event)"
```

so you can play with the event and see what's happening:

```
onShow(event) {
  console.log(event);
  // ...
}

onHidden(event) {
  // ...
}
```